# Mac OS X USB drivers for UWB wireless adapter to a Samsung Syncmaster display?

Tags: macos

I recently bought a Samsung Syncmaster C24A650X, a 24-inch display that features UWB wireless connection for everything. They gave me a wireless dongle for the display, and an USB adapter for the computer.

Currently I have one VGA cable and an USB cable between the computer and the display (the display also does USB hub, so my mouse/keyboard/devices are connected permanently to the display).

I wish I could use the wireless adapter to get rid of both cables. I tried to plug the USB dongle on my MacBook, but nothing happened and the screen had no signal.

I can't seem to find any information or driver on the Internet, because everything I get is "Samsung unveils its *** screen featuring UWB" without any driver, explanation or how-to guide.

Comment: I have googled for an hour to find an answer, and I did not. :\
On every website it says that there is driver needed for this feauture to work but nowhere I can find a link for download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to try

**Method 1**

1. Attach power adapter
2. Attach display USB dongle
3. Close MacBook lid and see if it switch to USB display mode

**Method 2**

**NO GARNETTE** I do not have a MacBook Pro here to test this out. I found it by Google.

[DisplayLink Driver For Mac USB Display](http://www.displaylink.com/support/mac_downloads.php)

It also stated it limitation on its download page. Following is the quote

> Please note: This driver does not support 3D acceleration. Some
>   features of Mac OS X-based applications that require hardware OpenGL
>   acceleration, such as Keynote presentations and iPhoto* slideshows,
>   will not function properly.

**Additional Info**

[Smart Station Setup (Software) (ver.1.6) Mac OS 10.7](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/LC24A650XS/ZA#)

Look into `Manuals & Downloads`, under `Software` (Not `Driver`).

Comment: I've tried both, neither works.

Comment: @Bicou there is a setup software for OS X, did you try that? Link in answer.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get back home. After the bounty expiration though... I'll set another one to reward you if this works!

Comment: Don't worry too much about bounty. I like bounty hunting because usually people are serious when posting bounty and will give feed back in the process :) Enjoy your holiday and Happy New Year!!

Comment: I think this is what I needed, it even installs the drivers for the Ethernet adapter that is on the screen. I'll blindly accept your answer :)

Comment: OK I came back home, this works.  I get a wireless display, USB hub and speakers since all of them are connected to the screen.  However even with the lid closed the MacBook's screen stays on.  And there is a very high latency in the display now, and all animations get a jpeg-like artifact until the image is still and the artifact is gone.  So I guess I'll stick to the HDMI and USB cables.

Comment: I was going to say I may getting something similar in future. Until I read the second half, sign. You can try it with a desktop machine, may get better result because of better cpu power.

Comment: I've got a core i5 with 4GB of RAM, I guessed that was enough... And the purpose of this wireless thing is to be useful with a laptop, not a desktop machine :)

Comment: I know. I was a bit surprise of the display performance too. However, I believe the display signal is being process by the cpu then send out via USB. That is the only explanation I can think of. Or the driver is not well written and not efficient.